# Prevent user from navigating to parent route inside feature module

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing, angular-module

I have an Angular 10 app with 2 feature modules. One for the landing page which can be reached with the `''` route, lazy-loading the feature module `LandingPageModule`. The second one is for a dashboard, which can be reached with the `'/dashboard'` route, lazy-loading the feature module `DashboardModule`.

Inside `DashboardModule`, I need a sidebar to stay visibile during the whole navigation of the user. I've used child routes to achieve this, so the sidebar can be added inside the parent component, and handle child route with `<router-outlet>`, allowing user to navigate through childroutes.

There are 3 child routes in the `DashboardRoutingModule` :

- `'/dashboard/summary'` loading `SummaryComponent`
- `'/dashboard/bookings'` loading `BookingListComponent`
- `'/dashboard/clients'` loading `ClientListComponent`

I made this [schema of the route workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkRnr.png) to complete my explanation.

Here you can find the code to achieve this

**AppRoutingModule**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./landing-page/landing-page.module').then(m => m.LandingPageModule) },
  { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: () => import('./dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule) },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**LandingPageRoutingModule**

```
const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: LandingPageComponent }];
```

**DashboardRoutingModule**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '', component: DashboardComponent, 
    children: 
    [
      { path: 'summary', component: SummaryComponent },
      { path: 'bookings', component: BookingListComponent },
      { path: 'clients', component: ClientListComponent },
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

**dashboard.component.html**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
    <div id="content">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>    
</div>
```

**My problem is**

When the user navigates to `/dashboard`, he gets the sidebar and a blank page next to it, because there isn't any component added below the `<router-outlet>`.

**My question is**

What should I do to prevent user to navigate manually to `/dashboard` ?

If I use `redirectTo`, the `DashboardComponent` isn't loaded and child routes aren't working at all.

Another good solution would be to remove the `/dashboard/summary` child route. When the user navigates to `/dashboard`, it would load the `SummaryComponent` as outlet for the router and keep the sidebar visible. But I couldn't find any way to make it work like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply had to add another child route handling the `''`.

**DashboardRoutingModule**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '', component: DashboardComponent, 
    children: 
    [
      { path: 'summary', component: SummaryComponent },
      { path: 'bookings', component: BookingListComponent },
      { path: 'clients', component: ClientListComponent },
      { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'summary'} //New child route handling ''
    ] 
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```